# Clustering (Apache 2.2.25 mod_jk + JBoss EAP 6.2) with Session Replication OFF and stickiness ON does not work

Tags: apache, mod-jk, jboss-eap-6, mod-cluster

I am using JBoss EAP 6.2 and Apache 2.2.25-no-ssl for load balancing and clustering deployment of my application.

I want **Session Replication off** and **Sticky session on**.

But after doing all sort of configurations, what I noticed that my load balancer not sticking user request based on session-id to one particular node, instead forwarding request to another node.

Below are my cluster configurations.

No of cluster nodes = 2

Apache Load balancer = Apache 2.2.25-no-ssl

App server = JBoss EAP 6.2.0

**Apache Load Balancer configuration**

**workers.properties**

```
# Define list of workers that will be used
# for mapping requests
worker.list=loadbalancer,status

# Define Node1
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=172.20.150.33
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.ping_mode=A
worker.node1.lbfactor=1 

# Define Node2
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node2.port=8209
worker.node2.host=172.20.150.33
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.ping_mode=A
worker.node2.lbfactor=1

# Load-balancing behavior
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=status
```

**uriworkermap.properties**

```
# Simple worker configuration file

# Mount the Servlet context to the ajp13 worker
/*=loadbalancer
```

**mod-jk.conf**

```
# Load mod_jk module
# Specify the filename of the mod_jk lib
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

# Where to find workers.properties
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel debug 

# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat  "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"

# JkOptions indicates to send SSK KEY SIZE
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

# JkRequestLogFormat
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

# Mount your applications
# The default setting only sends Java application data to mod_jk.
# Use the commented-out line to send all URLs through mod_jk.
# JkMount /* loadbalancer
JkMount /* loadbalancer

# Add shared memory.
# This directive is present with 1.2.10 and
# later versions of mod_jk, and is needed for
# for load balancing to work properly
JkShmFile logs/jk.shm 

# You can use external file for mount points.
# It will be checked for updates each 60 seconds.
# The format of the file is: /url=worker
# /examples/*=loadbalancer
JkMountFile conf/uriworkermap.properties

# Add jkstatus for managing runtime data
<Location /jkstatus/>
JkMount status
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

mod-jk.conf loaded in httpd.conf file and Apache runs on port 80.

In JBoss EAP, create two replica named **node1** and **node2** of **standalone** folder on same machine as depicted below

[image]

**Command to start server :**

**node1**

```
standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -b 172.20.150.33 -u 230.0.10.0 -Djboss.server.base.dir=../node1 -Djboss.node.name=node1 -Dlogging.configuration=file:/${JBOSS_HOME}/node1/configuration/logging.properties
```

**node2**

```
standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -b 172.20.150.33 -u 230.0.10.0 -Djboss.server.base.dir=../node2 -Djboss.node.name=node2 -Dlogging.configuration=file:/${JBOSS_HOME}/node2/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=200
```

I tried with Session Replication On (by adding  in web.xml) but still same problem exists.

Below are my JSESSIONID observations.

**on first request**

```
JSESSIONID = SY1d0wVTmX2b-czp50whdmCW.61423f3f-b623-3da4-bd2f-69ba448af636 where 61423f3f-b623-3da4-bd2f-69ba448af636 is JVM-ROUTE for node2.
```

on second request

```
JSESSIONID = QMTCTAzt2u-ANTidqZdBIzxO.f742b8d4-46f7-3914-86bb-1044d0a1bfce where f742b8d4-46f7-3914-86bb-1044d0a1bfce is a JVM-ROUTE for node1.
```

It seems even though jvm-route is appended to primary session id , still load balancer(apache mod-jk) sending request to other node instead of sticking to one on which session established.

Please do helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of scenario you need to implement this architecture. We are using the same architecture to host [Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/)

**Note: Please do not forget to enable session stickiness/connection persistency on Load Balancer(LB) and Apache mod_jk.**

**In this architecture:**

For

```
   WEB1 -> App1 is Active APP NODE
   WEB2 -> APP2 is Active APP NODE
```

So if request/connection comes ON LB it is redirected to WEB1. As session stickiness/connection persistency is enabled on LB All requests coming from the same client are redirected to WEB1 only.

Here is my **Apache Load Balancer configuration**:

**workers.properties For node1**

```
# Define list of workers that will be used
# for mapping requests
# The configuration directives are valid
# for the mod_jk version 1.2.18 and later
#
worker.list=loadbalancer,status

# Define Node1
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=10.62.147.58
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1
#worker.node1.socket_timeout=600
#worker.node1.ping_timeout=1000
worker.node1.ping_mode=A
#worker.node1.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.node1.redirect=node2


# Define Node2
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node2.port=8009
worker.node2.host=10.62.147.59
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.lbfactor=1
#worker.node2.socket_timeout=600
#worker.node2.ping_timeout=1000
worker.node2.ping_mode=A
#worker.node2.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.node2.activation=disabled

# Load-balancing behavior
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1
worker.loadbalancer.retry_interval=30
worker.loadbalancer.recover_time=20
#worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session_force=1

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=status
```

**workers.properties For node2**

```
# Define list of workers that will be used
# for mapping requests
# The configuration directives are valid
# for the mod_jk version 1.2.18 and later
#
worker.list=loadbalancer,status

# Define Node1
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=10.62.147.58
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1
#worker.node1.socket_timeout=600
#worker.node1.ping_timeout=1000
worker.node1.ping_mode=A
#worker.node1.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.node1.activation=disabled


# Define Node2
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node2.port=8009
worker.node2.host=10.62.147.59
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.lbfactor=1
#worker.node2.socket_timeout=600
#worker.node2.ping_timeout=1000
worker.node2.ping_mode=A
#worker.node2.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.node2.redirect=node1

# Load-balancing behavior
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1
worker.loadbalancer.retry_interval=30
worker.loadbalancer.recover_time=20
#worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session_force=1

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=status
```

**mod-jk.conf**

```
# Load mod_jk module
# Specify the filename of the mod_jk lib
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

# Where to find workers.properties
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel info

# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"

# JkOptions indicates to send SSK KEY SIZE
# Notes:
# 1) Changed from +ForwardURICompat.
# 2) For mod_rewrite compatibility, use +ForwardURIProxy (default since 1.2.24)
# See http://tomcat.apache.org/security-jk.html
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompatUnparsed -ForwardDirectories +ForwardURIProxy +ForwardURICompat


# JkRequestLogFormat
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

# Mount your applications
#JkMount /__application__/* loadbalancer
# Let Apache serve the images
#JkUnMount /__application__/images/* loadbalancer

# You can use external file for mount points.
# It will be checked for updates each 60 seconds.
# The format of the file is: /url=worker
# /examples/*=loadbalancer
JkMountFile conf/uriworkermap.properties

# Add shared memory.
# This directive is present with 1.2.10 and
# later versions of mod_jk, and is needed for
# for load balancing to work properly
# Note: Replaced JkShmFile logs/jk.shm due to SELinux issues. Refer to
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225452
JkShmFile run/jk.shm

JkMount /* loadbalancer
# Add jkstatus for managing runtime data
<Location /jkstatus>
JkMount status
Order deny,allow
Deny from none
Allow from All
</Location>
```